# How to Check for 2D Collision Without Checking Every Object

Tags: java, 2d, collision

I'm being really ambitious and working on a 2D Shoot 'em Up game that will have, hopefully, hundreds of entities running around.

What I'm having trouble wrapping my brain around, is how the bullet will detect when it makes a collision with an object, without it checking for every object on the map.  The reason is that I feel that if I have four dozen bullets on the screen, each checking for collision with every entity on the map, every cycle, I will see some fairly significant performance loss.

So what would be the best way to detect for collisions without checking every single entity?

I can handle the collision algorithm when I have my two objects, I just can't seem to find a way to get those two object to see each other without checking everyone else first.

I'm working in Java and OpenGL with (soon to be textured) QUADS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should investigate [*quadtrees*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree); they're often used for efficient 2D lookup.

Comment: +1, To add: there are many open-source quadtree projects around if you look for them.